# Dynamic list of valid str inputs for a Pydantic Field

Tags: python, list, literals, pydantic

I need to pass in a list of valid inputs to a field in Pydantic, but I don't know what that list will include until runtime (logged-in users, date range for next 7 days, etc).

Passing in multiple values for this field is valid (selecting 2 users who have logged in is fine, but selecting 1 who hasn't is not).

Things I've tried look something like have revolved around [`Literal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal), `List`, and [`Union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union):

```py
VALID = get_valid_inputs()

class ClassName(BaseModel):
    option_1: Literal[VALID] # Error: Type arguments for "Literal" must be None, a literal value (int, bool, str, or bytes), or an enum value
    option_2: List[VALID] # This does not throw an error, but also does not work the way I'm looking for. It requires a list with every value from VALID, whereas I'm looking for anywhere from 1, 2, or all of them.
```

I've done quite a lot of digging on this, but somehow haven't found anything, and I'm still relatively new to Pydantic. Apologies if it's a duplicate.

Comment: If that list can be "basically whatever", what is even the point of the Pydantic schema? You cannot parse "whatever" in any meaningful sense. You cannot do validation on "whatever". I am curious. Can you elaborate what the use case for this would be? If I misunderstood you, please provide an example that includes initialization of such a model and some desired output.

Comment: Hi @DaniilFajnberg, there are a few situations where we need to do this. One is translation. Because the languages our system will have translations for will change, in this case the output of the `get_valid_inputs()` function, I can't have a list of every language in the language Field. We have a few live today, several dozen coming soon, and many more after that. Another example would be countries. We're currently focusing on about 10, but know we want to add more later. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic type annotations are a contradiction in terms. It is theoretically impossible to perform static type checks on annotations that are only defined at runtime. This is also the reason, why things like `Literal` only support, well, *literals* and not arbitrary variables, unpacking or function calls.

For this reason, I would strongly recommend rethinking your design and if you *really* only know the types at runtime. If the situation is such that you *do* know the type of a field (e.g. `str`) in advance, but you want to restrict it to specific valid *values*, which you will only know about at runtime, you have a few options.

---

### Dynamic definition of an `Enum`

Pydantic allows restricting [choices](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#enums-and-choices) via the standard library's `enum.Enum` type. And the `EnumMeta` provides a [functional API](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/enum.html#functional-api), which allows you to define enum members dynamically.

Here is working demo:

```py
from enum import Enum
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError

def get_valid_inputs() -> tuple[str, ...]:
    return "foo", "bar", "baz"

...

Valid = Enum(  # type: ignore[misc]
    "Valid",
    ((value, value) for value in get_valid_inputs()),
    type=str,
)

class Model(BaseModel):
    single: Valid
    multiple: list[Valid] = []

def test() -> None:
    instance = Model(single="foo", multiple=["baz", "bar"])
    print(instance, "\n")
    try:
        Model(single="invalid")
    except ValidationError as e:
        print(e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

Output:

```
single=<Valid.foo: 'foo'> multiple=[<Valid.baz: 'baz'>, <Valid.bar: 'bar'>] 

1 validation error for Model
single
  value is not a valid enumeration member; permitted: 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' [...])
```

One drawback of this is that you'll have no static type checker support for the enum members because they are defined dynamically. E.g. your IDE will not give you useful hints/auto-suggestions for `Valid` members. In fact, `mypy` will complain about the way we define the enum because we did not provide a literal value as the second argument for `Enum`, which is why I put the `type: ignore` there.

---

### Custom `str` subclass with validation

Pydantic also allows you to define [custom data types](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#custom-data-types) that provide their own validation logic. You could therefore subclass `str` and set the valid choices on that class, while you define it. Then you could have a method for validation that simply checks if the provided value is among the valid choices. Here is an example for that approach:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from collections.abc import Callable, Iterator
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError

...

class Valid(str):
    __choices__ = get_valid_inputs()

    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls) -> Iterator[Callable[..., Valid]]:
        yield cls.validate

    @classmethod
    def __modify_schema__(cls, field_schema: dict[str, object]) -> None:
        field_schema.update(enum=list(cls.__choices__))

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, v: str) -> Valid:
        if not isinstance(v, str):
            raise TypeError("string required")
        if v not in cls.__choices__:
            raise ValueError(f"'{v}' is invalid; choices: {cls.__choices__}")
        return cls(v)

class Model(BaseModel):
    single: Valid
    multiple: list[Valid] = []

...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

Using the same `get_valid_inputs` and `test` functions as before, the output is equivalent:

```
single='foo' multiple=['baz', 'bar'] 

1 validation error for Model
single
  'invalid' is invalid; choices: ('foo', 'bar', 'baz') (type=value_error)
```

The `__modify_schema__` method is not necessary, but illustrates how you can modify what the JSON schema of your model will look like, if you intend to use it with such a customized `str` type.

---

From the examples you mentioned briefly in your comment it still seems to me, that the valid options are *actually* to be considered static (i.e. not known strictly at runtime), just changing relatively frequently. If that is the case, you may want to consider actually hard-coding them. If you don't want to do that by hand every time they change, you can also look into [datamodel generation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/datamodel_code_generator/) programs.

Comment: Hi @Daniil Fajnberg, these look really useful. Thanks for sharing! The data model generation in particular looks like exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Thanks @Daniil Fajnberg ! Would you consider the valid choices "known only at runtime" if they are derived from a database (i.e. pull/read from another data source) ? I believe this scenario happens quite frequently when valid choices are defined outside the scope of the code itself (say by external users).

Comment: @IgorOA Yes. In that case no static type hint is possible, obviously. You _could_ just use a Pydantic validator that connects to the database every time, but I don't think that is generally a good idea because it would severely slow down parsing/validation of the entire model. Such validation should probably only happen at the point of database interaction since that is where the constraint comes from. I think people often misuse Pydantic by trying to make their models perform functions they really are not meant for. That is one such case IMO.